# Deconstruct string and reformat

Tags: excel

I was wondering if anybody could assist me with a formula that could produce the following:

Information

[image: Example Info]

The information in Col A is the starting data and i want to deconstruct the string to split the data as it is in the orange columns.

Grateful for any input!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement below formula in cell `B1` and then copy down and across as much needed.

`=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(" "&TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"("," "),")"," "),"-"," "))," ",REPT(" ",99)),99*COLUMNS($A1:A1),99))`

which will first remove characters such as `()-` and then create string with lots of spaces of 99 character lengths and then using MID formula they'll be cut to specific portions. A good write up is available in following link:

https://excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/333-Get-Field-from-Delimited-Text-String?s=7fbe54dcc78a016b0ed36596f1248da0

Comment: Many thanks Shirval. That formula works great. The only thing i want to check with it is if it could move the words "Nap" and "nb" to show first followed by the numbers present in the cells... ?

Comment: @zonder you should be able to grasp the field logic by reading Rick's post.